# ngStorage - Reset to default values

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-storage

I'm using ngStorage for web storage.

And this is the code I'm currently using to check whether the `$localStorage` is defined or not.

```
if ( angular.isDefined($localStorage.settings) ) {
    $scope.app.settings = $localStorage.settings;
} else {
    $localStorage.settings = $scope.app.settings;
}
```

And this is my controller script.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {

    $scope.app = {
        settings: {
            name: 'AppName',
            headerFixed: true,
            version: 'Initial Release'
        }
    }

    if ( angular.isDefined($localStorage.settings) ) {
        $scope.app.settings = $localStorage.settings;
    } else {
        $localStorage.settings = $scope.app.settings;
    }

    $scope.resetStorage = function() {
        $localStorage.$reset();
    }

})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="{'header-fixed': app.settings.headerFixed}">

        <input type="checkbox" name="name" ng-model="app.settings.headerFixed"> Header Fixed

        {{ app.settings.headerFixed }}

        <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="resetStorage()">Reset</button>

</div>
```

I'm using the rest method as given in the this [link](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage), but it doesn't work.

Someone help me out to reset my values to the default values when I click a reset button where I'm calling the function `resetStorage()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another way is to store default values in an `object` and on `click`, please assign this `object value` to your `localstorage object`. I did the same in one of my projects.

Comment: You mean to say.. `$localStorage.settings = $scope.app.settings`?

Comment: Tried it already, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Nope.. Nothing. But I figured out a solution. I duplicated the $scope.app object inside the function and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep two variables one for use another for restore purpose .
because i think no such method available that can restore back to the previous data.

Comment: It should be a comment.

Comment: had no permissions that's y .. :D